# Javascript/Jquery Uncaught typeerror trying to replace html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

trying to remove some text on my site using jQuery after the page has finished loading, and the code isn't working. When looking at the JS console in Chrome, I get the following error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined`.

Here's my code for replacing the text:

```
<script>
window.onload = function(){
  var replaced = $("footer-copy").html().replace("'s Frontpage",'');
  $("footer-copy").html(replaced);
};
</script>
```

And the HTML I'm trying to update:

```
<div class="footer-wrap">
    <div class="footer-copy">© 2017 <a href="https://blog.andrewgottschling.me/">Andrew Gottschling's Frontpage</a> Powered by <a href="https://leafpub.org" target="_blank">Leafpub</a></div>
    <div class="footer-design-author"><span>Design with</span> <i class="i-favorite heart"></i> by <a href="https://leafpub.org" target="_blank" title="Desarrollador Web FullStack.">@leafpub</a></div>
</div>
```

Thanks for all the help in advance. :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add a class selector, otherwise jQuery searches for a tag with that name.

```
var replaced = $(".footer-copy").html().replace("'s Frontpage",'');
```

Notice the dot before the class name.

Comment: Thanks. Don't know how I missed that.

Answer (score 2):

To find an element using class name, you need prepend this class with dot:

```
$(".footer-copy")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the class selector "." before the class name. Like this:

```
<script>
window.onload = function(){
  var replaced = $(".footer-copy").html().replace("'s Frontpage",'');
  $(".footer-copy").html(replaced);
};
</script>
```